# Looking for ansible solution to read standalone.xml files on wildfly

Tags: ansible, wildfly, centos7

looking for a solution to gather and organize standalone.xml files from various wildfly servers grouped by "staging" or "production" in my hosts file.

looking to see if something is available with the same output functionality of:

> ansible wildfly -m setup --tree config

which creates a file per host with the requested data.

for example if i have 4 servers each one having a file named the exact same, in the same path, but having different contents. i could have them copied to a local directory and named after the server it came from:

> (E.G:
>
> standalone.server1.myserver.com
>
> standalone.server2.myserver.com
>
> )

Answer (score 0):

Use the Ansible [fetch](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/fetch_module.html) module which has a few examples:

A very simple playbook may look like:

```
hosts: widlfy
tasks:
  - name: Store file into /tmp/fetched/{hostname}/tmp/somefile
    fetch:
      src: /tmp/somefile
      dest: /tmp/fetched
```

Run the playbook:
    `ansible-playbook playbook.yml`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `fetch` module, e.g as ad hoc command:

```
ansible wildfly -i myInventory -m fetch -a "src=/myRemotePathname/standalone dest=/myLocalPathName/myDir" -u myUser
```

You'll get the remote file `standalone` file from the remote directory `/myRemotePathname` of any host belonging to `wildfly` group defined in `myInventory` file.
Local files are stored in a local `/myLocalPathName/myDir` directory having a subdirectory named as the remote hosts and under that the remote directory path.